If I have x and y coordinates of a point along the arc, how do I convert that to a percentage of PI?
I am using Javascript to create shapes in canvas. I am creating an arc where you specify the start and end angle of the arc to show where along a circle the arc begins and ends. They are initially set as a percentage of PI like so:
              1.5 * PI
              *  
           *     * 
          *       *
 1 * PI - *   *    * - 0 * PI
          *       *
           *     * 
              *  
              0.5 * PI

If I have x and y coordinates of a point along the arc, how do I convert that to a percentage of PI?
Example of what I've created:
Arc with two red control points
For this implementation, I have the red circles bound to the arc so when you drag them they stay along the arc path. So given the x,y coordinates of the draggable red circle, I need to update the arc path so that it matches the movement of the control points. If I have a start angle at 1PI and an end angle at 0PI, if I move the control point to an x,y coordinate equivalent to 1.5PI, I need to convert those coordinates to something like 1.5PI.

In my scenario, I define the start of the arc as 0.75 * Math.PI and the end of the arc at 0.25 * Math.PI At those points I created a draggable shape and I want to use to change the length of the arc by changing the start and end angles.

I'm not sure I understand correctly, but is it safe to assume that the point $(x , y)$ always lays on a circle of radius $r$ and midpoint $(x_m, y_m)$?

See my answer to a similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4934077/calculating-percentage-coordinates-on-an-arc/4934087#4934087

Given a point, $p$, subtract the center and scale by the radius $(p-c)/r$.  Then use Math.atan2 to get your answer in radians, $\theta$.  Finally, display "$\theta/\pi$ PI" (i.e., factor out the $\pi$ you intend to print as text).
